# Does jQuery's blur event focus another element on a page?

Tags: jquery, events, blur

I understand that calling jQuery events `$(selector).blur();` will call `trigger` and run the blur event handler(s).

Does this give any other element on the page e.g. document, body, focus?

N.B. While this seems fairly simple I have not found details on the jQuery API or SO or Google.

Comment: See my edit. It's different in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it gives any other element focus. It seems to just take focus away completely (actually, not in IE see my edit). I wired up a jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jkXxa/) along these lines:

**HTML**

```
<div id="test">
    <input id="test2" />
    <input id="test3" />
    <input id="test4" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    $('*').focus(function() {
        alert(this.id);
    });
    $('input').keypress(function(evt) {
        if (evt.which == '13') {
            $(this).blur();
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Basically, it alerts when any element receives focus and when you press enter in any of the input boxes, it calls `.blur()`. In Opera no other element gets focus when this happens. In Firefox the alert box takes focus away from the element so you need to use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` but it acts the same way otherwise.

**Edit**
I checked it in IE and it seems that focus is changed to the body element. If you have it `alert(this);` instead of `alert(this.id);` it says that the body element gets focus when the inputs lose it.